# Timer object exists beyond window object lifetime

Tags: c#

I'm showing a `Forms` window as dialogbox

```
private void buttonOverview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (new OverviewBox()).ShowDialog();
    MessageBox.Show("Window Exited");
}
```

`OverviewBox` has a refresh timer that is instantiated within the constructor

```
public OverviewBox()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this._polltimer = new Timer { Interval = 30000, Enabled = true };
    this._polltimer.Tick += (sender, e) => { this.Poll(); };
}
```

The method `Poll` asynchronously gets data from the database and updates the view without freezing it.

```
private void Poll()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (!SessionContext.Connectable())
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            [logics to get data]
            this.dgvChangeCoordinators.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { SetDataGridView(this.dataGridView, "<Data Description>", listwithdata); }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    });
}
```

`SetDataGridView` sets the list as `itemsource` of a `datagridview` and displays the data description. Sometimes however, my users complain about exceptions. The exception log looks like this:

```
7/15/2013 5:00:10 PM:
System.InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate method)
at FormulierGenerator.Views.Agent.OverviewBox.<Poll>b__5()


7/15/2013 5:00:23 PM:
System.InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate method)
at FormulierGenerator.Views.Agent.OverviewBox.<Poll>b__5()


7/15/2013 5:00:40 PM:
System.InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate method)
at FormulierGenerator.Views.Agent.OverviewBox.<Poll>b__5()


7/15/2013 5:00:53 PM:
System.InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate method)
at FormulierGenerator.Views.Agent.OverviewBox.<Poll>b__5()
```

From the time difference between the exceptions, I conclude that at least two instances of the timer are still active (30 seconds between polls, 4 different times for which groups of 2 are within 30 seconds, the poll interval). However, I cannot simulate the issue by just starting and closing the overview twice.

I suspect a `GC` related issue where the window object is collected at some point in time, but the poller keeps on existing. When it tries to update the window in the window thread context, it fails. But then, shouldn't the Window object and all it's content only exist in the context of  private void `buttonOverview_Click`? Added a MessageBox.Show() call to the button method to test if the method is completed after closing the dialog. It does show.

Set a breakpoint on the `Poll` method to see if it was still called after the dialog was closed. It was, so the poller is definitely living longer then the window is visible. My question is, are my conclusions correct so far? If so, how can the poller continue to exist even though the context wherein the object creating the timer has been instantiated, is no longer existent e.g. how to prevent the poller from living on way past window close? Thinking of an unload event action but do not know if that is the best solution.

Comment: `BeginInvoke()` does not make your code asynchronous.  You don't need it at all.

Comment: Have you tried starting your timer inside the "Loaded" event of your window?

Comment: @SuperOli going to try this now, but will take some time because I'm not yet able to reproduce the error.

Comment: I think you are incorrectly concluding that closing the dialogbox is killing the OverviewBox object. Are you making sure of that in the code ? I think that even if the dialog is no longer visible, the OverviewBox may still be living, and with it, its timer.

Comment: @SLaks BeginInvoke() is called from a thread created by Task.Run. To my understanding, it is not possible to update the UI from threads other then the Window thread. To my understanding I need to Invoke anything that updates the window directly in the window thread. If I'm wrong, could you elaborate?

Comment: @C4stor That might be a lead. I'm not making sure the dialogbox is killed. I was assuming that objects declared in a method, only survive the method context. Could you explain my mistake?

Comment: You are right, but are you sure that the onClick method has actually returned ? It may very well be still hanging for whatever reason. Try to output something at the very end of the click method, and see if this is called maybe ?

Comment: It should also help to unregister to the Timer.Tick event when you close the OverviewBox.

Comment: @C4stor tested it by adding a messagebox, the method seems to run  to finish after closing the dialogbox.

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann going to try this now. Could you perhaps explain why the registration to an object declared in a object context persists beyond the lifetime of the object itself?

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann Alright, as I see it now: Objects with a reference are not collected by GC. However the Window is no longer referenced to, the event still has active subscriptions. This causes the GC to not remove the Timer which keeps it running in background. Exceptions are seemingly thrown whenever the Window itself is GC'ed. Going to test this now.

Comment: Don't think it has anything to do with GC but rather with the way forms work. When the window is closed, the window object which is being used in the invoke call is immediately unreachable. Going to test with a separate class instead of the form, then post the answer to this question

Comment: @RamonBertrand: You're right; I missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the Garbage Collector isn't deterministic. Even if your window is closed and not referenced anywhere, a possibly long time can elapse before the window is actually collected. You should unsubscribe from the `Tick` event and set `IsEnabled` to `false` as soon as the window is closed.

That being said, the real problem here is the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` itself. As soon as it's enabled, it allocates a [`GCHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx) for itself, preventing its garbage collection. The event handler then prevents the window from being collected, not the other way as it's usually the case, and as you think is happening.

Note that `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` disables itself when its disposed, preventing this problem, and all components of a `Form` are automatically disposed when the form closes. But you're not registering the `Timer` as a form component, thus `Dispose` is never called automatically. You should add a `Timer` to your form through the toolbox, or instantiate it using `new Timer(components)` to see the problem disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Need to turn the tick into a named method

```
this._polltimer.Tick += _polltimer_Tick;
```

And unregister when closing the form

```
    private void OverviewBox_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this._polltimer.Tick -= this._polltimer_Tick;
    }
```

Not unregistering prevents the Timer from being destroyed, because there are still active references to it. Closing the form however destroys the elements on the form, causing the issue when calling invoke.

Many thanks to all the people who replied especially to @BenjaminBaumann for providing the clue that lead to this answer.